# How do I do complex positioning of my subfigures?

Tags: positioning, subfloats, subcaption

I'm writing my bachelors thesis, and I have som trouble positioning my subfigures. I have three figures in different sizes, and I would like to have an output like this:

[image]

I tried typing the following code:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\multirow{2}{*}{%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.38\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[trim=8cm 8.5cm 8cm 4cm,clip,width=.5\textwidth]{fig/mast01.eps}
\end{subfigure}} &%
\begin{subfigure}{.58\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[trim=13cm 11cm 2.5cm 12cm,clip,width=.6\textwidth]{fig/mast01.eps}
\end{subfigure} \\ &%
\begin{subfigure}{.58\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[trim=7cm 16cm 2.5cm 2cm,clip,width=.6\textwidth]{fig/mast02.eps}
\end{subfigure} \\%
\end{tabular}
\caption{Teknisk tegning af gittermasten}
\label{fig:gittermast}
\end{figure}
```

... but the output looks horrible.

How can I do this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may measure the left image and then build a minipage with the same height containing the other two images (as `subfigure` environments).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\newsavebox{\bigimage}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering

\sbox{\bigimage}{%
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{.38\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-9x16}
  \caption{Figure 1}

  \vspace{0pt}% reference point at the very bottom
  \end{subfigure}%
}

\usebox{\bigimage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b][\ht\bigimage][s]{.58\textwidth}
  \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=3.5cm,width=\textwidth]{example-image-16x9}
  \caption{Figure 2}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \vfill
  \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=3.5cm,width=\textwidth]{example-image-16x9}
  \caption{Figure 3}
  \end{subfigure}

  \vspace{0pt}% reference point at the very bottom
\end{minipage}

\caption{Full caption}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

But there's a slicker way, which requires low level TeX constructs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering

\tabskip=0pt
\valign{#\cr
  \hbox{%
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.38\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-9x16}
    \caption{Figure 1}
    \end{subfigure}%
  }\cr
  \noalign{\hfill}
  \hbox{%
    \begin{subfigure}{.58\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=3.5cm,width=\textwidth]{example-image-16x9}
    \caption{Figure 2}
    \end{subfigure}%
  }\vfill
  \hbox{%
    \begin{subfigure}{.58\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=3.5cm,width=\textwidth]{example-image-16x9}
    \caption{Figure 3}
    \end{subfigure}%
  }\cr
}

\caption{Full caption}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like the second solution. However, the perfect alignment of figure 1 and 3 is lost if the heights of the captions (a) and (c) are not equal.

Comment: How can I add 3 sub figures in 2 rows in this format?

Comment: @RAHULLALP This format doesn't have rows, has it?