# How to put 5 images with different sizes in Latex

Tags: graphics

I want to put together five images in Latex as shown in the image:

[image: 1]

I tried tabular, subfigure, subfloat, but I didn't manage to get to something similar to that. I'm new to Latex!

Thank you for the help.

This is my code which get me this images [image]:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{llp{5cm}}
    Caption & Caption & \\
    \hspace{-100px}
    \includegraphics[width=6cm]{mean_fall.png}
    &
    \hspace{-50px}
    \includegraphics[width=6cm]{mean_spring.png}
    & Caption\\
    Caption & Caption & 
    \hspace{-100px}
    \includegraphics[width=10cm]{mean_annual.png}
    \vspace{-150px}\\
    \hspace{-100px}
    \includegraphics[width=6cm]{mean_summer.png}
    &
    \hspace{-50px}
    \includegraphics[width=6cm]{mean_winter.png} 
    & \\ 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem. While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222641/how-do-i-do-complex-positioning-of-my-subfigures can help

Comment: Unfortunately your code fragment does not compile. It seems that some packages are missing.

Comment: @samcarter I'm using Overleaf, I checked the errors and cleared out some parts. Now, at least in Overleaf, I don't see any errors.

Comment: Please don't use images that we don't have in your MWEs. Use `example-pictures` as in Fran's and samcarter answers.

Comment: @sztruks Even better: `example-image-duck` from the `duckuments` package :)

Answer (score 3):

`minipage`s are an easy way to place things besides each other. To add caption you could use the `subcaption` package - or if you don't need the numbering - just write them manually.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

\begin{minipage}{.25\textwidth}
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\subcaption{heading}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\subcaption{heading}
\end{subfigure}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.25\textwidth}
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\subcaption{heading}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\subcaption{heading}
\end{subfigure}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\subcaption{heading}
\end{subfigure}
\end{minipage}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A few seconds late :P

Comment: @Fran indeed :)

Answer (score 2):

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\belowcaptionskip1ex
\begin{multicols}{3}
\caption{Image A}\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Image  B}\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{Image  C}\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
\caption{Empty Image}\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-plain}\newpage\vspace*{\fill}
\caption{Image Image}\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}\vspace*{\fill}
\end{multicols}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I thought you need package `mwe` to load those images. Are they part of the LaTeX base now?

Comment: @sztruks Try yourself.  The package is not needed. The images are in a searchable directory.

Comment: @sztruks The mwe package needs to be installed, but you don't need to load it in the document.

Comment: That is what I meant. I did not explain clearly, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

I find it easier with a nested `tabular`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

\centering

\begin{tabular}{@{} c c @{}}
  \begin{tabular}{@{} c c @{}}
    Title & Title \\[1ex]
    \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{example-image} &
    \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{example-image} \\[2ex]
    Title & Title \\[1ex]
    \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{example-image} &
    \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{example-image}
  \end{tabular}
&
  \begin{tabular}{@{} c @{}}
    Title \\[1ex]
    \includegraphics[width=4.5cm,height=4.5cm]{example-image}
  \end{tabular}
\end{tabular}

\caption{Global caption}\label{whatever}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I used both `width` and `height` to make the pictures square as your question shows.